# td-agent is not working for apache logs

Tags: apache, mongodb, logging, apache2, fluentd

I need one help, I'm also using td-agent newest version at my ubuntu 12.04 for parsing apache logs to mongodb, in config if i put "format none", then it creates a mongo document and pushes everything to message key, but when I say "format apache" or "format apache2" or "format /^***********$/" (which is apache regular expression given by td-agent itself) then simply it says pattern not matched,

I checked the permissions, other ways around and all, but didn't get a solution for this, please help me, if u were able to run your logging project using td-agent(Fluentd).

Or should I shift to Logtrash for accomplishing this project.

the /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log warnings are following.

2015-02-09 18:41:39 +0530 [warn]: pattern not match: "192.168.100.11:80 192.168.100.11 - - [09/Feb/2015:18:41:39 +0530] \"POST /get_details HTTP/1.1\" 200 580 \"http://192.168.100.11/login\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0\""

2015-02-09 18:41:39 +0530 [warn]: pattern not match: "192.168.100.11:80 192.168.100.11 - - [09/Feb/2015:18:41:39 +0530] \"POST /get_user HTTP/1.1\" 200 365 \"http://192.168.100.11/login\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0\""

Thanks,
Williams.

Comment: Got the solution, it was regular expression issue, :D

Answer (score 0):

Must be regexp issue. This site would be a great help.
http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/